# Are there any situations that I can say "I suggested to ...?"

Tags: prepositions, complementation

From my understanding, **suggest** should be in form of "I suggest someone do something." Today I read an article about [Regular Expression Algorithms](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr09/cos333/beautiful.html) and the author wrote:

> I **suggested to** Rob that we needed to find the smallest regular
>   expression

I was wondering if it's a correct usage. If it is correct, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're feeling ill?  I suggest (that) you take two aspirin and call me in the morning.

You don't know the city?  May I suggest the Ritz Carlton hotel?

The last train has left?   I suggested to her that she stay the night with us.

She was looking for something easy but interesting to read? I suggested a book which had won the Newbery Medal.

All idiomatic uses of *suggest*. It takes direct as well as indirect objects, and object-complement phrases.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine.

> ".....suggest **to**.... **that**...." --seems to be a valid structure.

[Merriam Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggest) has one such entry:

> *"We suggested **to** the committee **that** they review the case again."*

But in most of the examples, I find *"....suggest someone"...* more common. Your doubt is valid! :)

Comment: You mean like _"I suggested (that) Rob rewrite the expression."_ ? That just says I made the suggestion that Rob should be the one to rewrite it - it doesn't say who I mentioned my suggestion to. Whether you need the "to" depends on the context.